# firefox addon sdk override link preview text

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm new to developing firefox addons and was wondering if there is a way to override/modify the link preview text that appears at the bottom of the browser when you hover over a link.

I've looked briefly and wasn't able to find any reference describing this.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: You could use a content script to change the actual URL of the link, but I'm guessing that's not the solution you're looking for. It's beyond the scope of the SDK, but someone with greater understanding of low-level chrome might be able to give you a non-SDK solution.

Comment: that may work - I will want to change multiple links on a page - that may actually be a great option.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the status text like this:

```
aDOMWindow.XULBrowserWindow.setOverLink('blah')
```

Where `aDOMWindow` is a `window` like that returned from for example `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser')`.

So like do link.addEventListener('onmouseenter'.... a function that does setOverLink

and to make it go away set it to blank string. So just `window.XULBrowserWindow.setOverLink('')`

But you are doing this on mouse enter of a link and by default mouse out of links will blank it so you may not neede to handle blanking it.

edit:
you asked about add-sdk, so the `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow` might not make sense, so here's a quick test you can try in sdk:

```
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
getMostRecentBrowserWindow().XULBrowserWindow.setOverLink('hiiiiiii!!!')
```

Comment: Great - thanks - that is some great direction.  I will try it out as soon as I have an opportunity and report back the results.